# Не устанавливается MS SQL SERVER на Ubuntu Server 18.04. Too many nested exception

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server

Выполняю установку по документации сама установка проходит. После выбора версии, установки языка и пароля выдает ошибку о сбое при начальной установке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сообщение в логах - "too many nested exception"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ubunta чистая-только установленная. гугл не дает никаких результатов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: случайно postgres не подходит?

Comment: не, нужен именно MS Sql под ASP Core

Comment: упорно не хочет ставиться именно на одну машину, на остальных все ок.

Comment: Может там места нет `df`; в том числе инодов `df -i`; или памяти `free`

Comment: сначала тоже на озу думал, было 2,4 ГБ подкинул еще плашку на 2 гб ничего не помогает, устанавливал убунту 16.04 та же ошибка

Comment: а место на накопителе? если много мелких файлов хранится -- могут иноды кончиться

Comment: прикрепил скриншот к самому вопросу. Не пойму в какой раздел должна установиться

Comment: всё тут нормально, 1 раздел "/", почти пустой... Может там проц 32-битный...Больше нету идей.